# Excel : Sum product with two criteria in a same column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need a help in excel. 
I would need a formula, which would total a range(column), while checking for a criteria within the same column.

In the below example,  i need to calculate the total of shoe disposed from the shoe original. ( answer should -899 (+) -566 = -1465

Original data runs for thousands of rows and it's not always sorted and no helper column, since data is generated by another department.

```
ColumnA     ColumnB       Column C
WAREHOUSEA B1D1567  ShoeDup        120
WAREHOUSEB B1O5732  ShoeOriginal   1000
WAREHOUSEA B1D234   ShoeDup        110
WAREHOUSEA B1D27809 ShoeDup     90
WAREHOUSEC B1D3211  ShoeDup        1230
WAREHOUSEA B1D4522  ShoeDup        1431
WAREHOUSEA B1O4098  ShoeOriginal    899
WAREHOUSEB B1O7651  ShoeOriginal    566
WAREHOUSEA B1O8976  ShoeOriginal    761
WAREHOUSEA B1O9811  ShoeOriginal    320
WAREHOUSEA B1O4098  ShoeDisposed    -899
WAREHOUSEA B1D1567  ShoeDisposed    -120
WAREHOUSEB B1O7651  ShoeDisposed    -566
WAREHOUSEA B1D27809 ShoeDisposed    -90
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you wamt to sum the "ShoeDisposed" rows where the ID in column A also has an entry for "ShoeOriginal". This "array formula" will do that with no regard to the order

`=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A20,IF(B1:B20="ShoeOriginal",A2:A20),0)),IF(B2:B20="ShoeDisposed",C2:C20)))`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Another way, which avoids using array formulas, is to add a helper column, e.g. this formula in D1 copied down

`=IF(B1="ShoeDisposed",IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,"ShoeOriginal"),C1,""),"")`

.....and sum column D for your answer

Note: `COUNTIFS` needs Excel 2007 or later

Comment: barry, this works perfectly for me :) what if i need to add one more column in the left like warehouseA, warehouseB... etc.. & in need to calculate the same only from warehouse A.. *Edited the original question*. Many thanks for your help :)

Comment: You can add another IF, e.g. `=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2:B20,IF(C1:C20="ShoeOriginal",B2:B20),0)),IF(C2:C20="ShoeDisposed",IF(A2:A20="WAREHOUSEA",D2:D20))))`